# Send whatsapp message without template

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

Is there a way to send a whatsapp message without template? I'm using the graph.facebook.com/v15.0 API and couldn't find any info about it

I'm trying this

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{phoneId}/messages' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer Token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "anyNumber",
    "text": {
        "body": "hello world!"
    }
}'
```

Comment: If you refer documentation, you will find the list of other types of messages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages

Comment: Hey @turivishal, thanks for the help. I tried to use that one but I'm getting this message.

`{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'phoneId' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": ""
    }
}`

Comment: You need to follow the documentation first, before executing everything, Every detail is mentioned in the getting started [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started).

Comment: @turivishal Yeah, thanks for the help man. I was using the wrong bearer token as well as the payload. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the error:

I was using the wrong payload. Thanks to @turivishal.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages

I was also using the wrong Bearer Token.